# Unable to create(POST) objects (Account, customer...) on QB Windows using IDS and Sync Manager

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Here I am provideing you the complete scenario where I am getting the error while posting request for creating a new account.

I am using Intuit OAuth Access and OAuth API console for testing (Using all security tokens).(https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth)

And the URL and request:

```
URL: https://services.intuit.com/sb/account/v2/570357960
```

Method : Post

Format: XML/JSON

```
Request:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><Add xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" RequestId="4df87bw2-916a-

4r95-h5d6-06dce3667562" 

xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"><ExternalRealmId>570357960</ExternalRealmId><Objectxsi:type="Account"><Name>CurrentAccount</Name><Active>true</Active><Type>Expense<

/Type><Subtype>Expense</Subtype><AcctNum>1111</AcctNum></Object></Add>
```

And getting the response (error in html):

```
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
```

and I have also checked with RESTClient utility, but getting the same above error.

> Please note that the same url
>   (https://services.intuit.com/sb/account/v2/570357960) with same
>   security tokens is working fine for GET data , I am getting data from
>   QB desktop into my online Application.

Comment: Post the rest of your HTTP request - e.g. your Content-Type and other HTTP headers.

Comment: ContentType: application/xml and Oauth credentials:  OAuth realm="https%3A%2F%2Fservices.intuit.com%2Fsb%2Faccount%2Fv2%2F570357960", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_nonce="5GUvzx2n8hzHhQd", oauth_timestamp="1358852371", oauth_consumer_key="qyprdj6FkwCXWoq9Q8oRYlz33HXfN8", oauth_token="qyprdOFFjaKyki2o9pKUt0OoXXuFdaOc4520PHrNsQh24NTK", oauth_signature="nClDmMfbDcurX0EjUJz69yxBtzQ%3D"

Comment: Getting error on RESTClient , different from Playground: <RestResponse>
<Error RequestId="4a778df7fff740ae9c28931649af473e">
<RequestName>ErrorRequest</RequestName>
<ProcessedTime>2013-01-22T10:57:42+00:00</ProcessedTime>
<ErrorCode>3200</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDesc>
message=Exception authenticating OAuth; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401; source=OAuthStrategy; oauth_problem=signature_invalid; cause=net.oauth.OAuthProblemException: signature_invalid
</ErrorDesc>
</Error>
</RestResponse>

Comment: ConsumerKey: qyprdj6FkwCXWoq9Q8oRYlz33HXfN8   ConsumerSecret: WHElfjFy5ip8C7UGFQdSRnl9hCeDq4fivvyxTnX6    AccessToken: qyprdOFFjaKyki2o9pKUt0OoXXuFdaOc4520PHrNsQh24NTK   TokenSecret:73yLwpW3VZg3So5gURbDrUBtXQkV5CjToCbb6rkI   And Request (body) is same as above.

Answer (score 1):

As Keith said, check the Content-Type.  You will also need to use a RestClient for testing. The playground will not work for testing API calls. It only works for platform calls.

Comment: My Issue resolved.
Use this new utilty from intuit to test: http://apiexplorer.developer.intuit.com

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess... I'd guess you're sending the wrong Content-Type header... but it's impossible to tell for sure until you post more code/the rest of your HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try. Be sure the XML is in the same order as this sample and try it.
the other is a common mistake when you use Oauth in a GET you are including just the url in the signature, but in a POST you need to include the Body in the signature too or it will not pass Oauth validation.

Lastly, as Keith mentioned to check the content type. Although you would generally get a content type error.

156234822
   
      CurrentAccount
      true
      Expense
      Expense
      1111