# Filtering with Quickbooks Online V2 returns 401 ErrorCode=003200, Empty body posts work perfectly

Tags: ruby, api, oauth, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

We're attempting to integrate with the QuickBooks Online V2 api using Ruby 1.9.3 **(not RoR)**.
Using the [API Explorer](https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBO#Employee) and the [Employee endpoint](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/employee) documentation we were able to get a simple list of test employees by using the [Google Signet OAuth Gem](https://github.com/google/signet).

```
require 'signet'
require 'signet/oauth_1/client'

#intialize oauth1 client
@client = Signet::OAuth1::Client.new(
    :temporary_credential_uri => "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token",
    :authorization_uri => "https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin",
    :token_credential_uri => "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token",
    :client_credential_key => 'qyprdPEfJqU7eOze0Fby9iYhrUS5DQ',
    :client_credential_secret => 'fuXsasJo4TrTEd3Yhv4TeMUizmtguh0JioIB5r2I',
    :callback => "http://localhost:3000/callback/general"
)

@client.token_credential_key = 'qyprdJUtDSk7owxVfZlq7JeWO1mtpHBkSMD5GhB02PwIC6N0'
@client.token_credential_secret = 'Rq2ekgQWWL9frZAKpcgWef291mR0J5HBE354u5F3'

#setup request
original_request = [
    'POST',
    'https://qbo.sbfinance.intuit.com/resource/employees/v2/791630875',
    # we also tried this url 'https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo28/resource/employees/v2/791630875',
    [
        ['Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    ],
    []
]
#execute request
response = @client.fetch_protected_resource(:request => original_request)
puts response.body
```

As you can see the request is pretty straight-forward. 
However once we create a request with a Filter in the body, we get an HTML page with the following error: `HTTP Status 401 - message=Exception authenticating OAuth; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401`

```
#setup request
original_request = [
    'POST',
    'https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo28/resource/employees/v2/791630875',
    #'https://qbo.sbfinance.intuit.com/resource/employees/v2/791630875',
    [
        ['Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    ],
    ["Filter=Name :EQUALS: Doe"]
]
```

We're using the Google OAuth gem, and I've verified the signature generation to be correct using these tools: [LinkedIn Oauth Test Console](https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console)  and [Beginners guide to OAuth signing requests](http://hueniverse.com/2008/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iv-signing-requests/). They both verify that the signature that Signet is generating is correct for the body I provide.

I've looked at a few SO Questions:

- [QuickBooks Online querying with filter returns 401 everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695065/quickbooks-online-querying-with-filter-returns-401-everytime)
- [Unable to create(POST) objects (Account, customer...) on QB Windows using IDS and Sync Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436914/unable-to-createpost-objects-account-customer-on-qb-windows-using-ids-an)

But nothing has worked. Any help would be appreciated, we're willing to use a third party gem such as [quickeebooks](https://github.com/ruckus/quickeebooks) but we would rather not. I assume I'm just missing something simple here.

Please provide me with the following items so I can verify a working answer:

- Your request parameters, including uri, header, body and exact client and access tokens (developer app tokens only please, I'll need to verify that I can generate the exact same request, including signature)
- You basestring used for generating the HMAC-SHA1  signature. it will look something like

`POST&https%3A%2F%2Fqbo.intuit.com%2Fqbo28%2Fresource%2Femployees%2Fv2%2F7916308‌​75&Filter%3DName%2520%253AEQUALS%253A%2520David%2520Test%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dq‌​yprdPEfJqU7eOze0Fby9iYhrUS5DQ%26oauth_nonce%3D-1787433535548338293%26oauth_signat‌​ure_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1380089100%26oauth_token%3DqyprdJUtDSk‌​7owxVfZlq7JeWO1mtpHBkSMD5GhB02PwIC6N0%26oauth_version%3D1.0`

- Your response, including header and body data

Answer (score 0):

I had tried to use filter query with employee endpoint. It works fine.

**EDIT** - Sharing endpoint, filter and resultset related to Employee API Endpoint

```
https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo28/resource/employees/v2/791926875

Filter= Name :EQUALS: Manas Mukherjee
```

header - `"Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="2eRrd7LhEtHrM1CrqWvy1kmSgeukEgFxW99E1xwhSsLCp1JB", oauth_consumer_key="qyprdXsaKh0a132eNs7NTJLufjfrzm", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1380084612", oauth_nonce="1556081845430558974", oauth_signature="IMjh%2FTx%2F7GMFDE6WQqZK8b6apjI%3D"[\r][\n]"`

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Data Set

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<qbo:SearchResults xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:qbp="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:qbo="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
    <qbo:CdmCollections xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Employees">
        <Employee>
            <Id idDomain="QBO">20</Id>
            <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
            <MetaData>
                <CreateTime>2013-09-24T21:37:22-07:00</CreateTime>
                <LastUpdatedTime>2013-09-24T21:37:22-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
            </MetaData>
            <Name>Manas Mukherjee</Name>
            <Address>
                <Line1>ABC Str</Line1>
                <City>London</City>
                <PostalCode>4353543</PostalCode>
                <GeoCode>LAT=51.5148382,LNG=-0.1264144</GeoCode>
            </Address>
            <GivenName>Manas</GivenName>
            <MiddleName>Kr</MiddleName>
            <FamilyName>Mukherjee</FamilyName>
            <ShowAs>Manas Kr Mukherjee</ShowAs>
            <BillableTime>false</BillableTime>
        </Employee>
    </qbo:CdmCollections>
    <qbo:Count>1</qbo:Count>
    <qbo:CurrentPage>1</qbo:CurrentPage>
</qbo:SearchResults>
```

OAuth header using **your** tokens

```
"Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="qyprdJUtDSk7owxVfZlq7JeWO1mtpHBkSMD5GhB02PwIC6N0", oauth_consumer_key="qyprdPEfJqU7eOze0Fby9iYhrUS5DQ", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1380089100", oauth_nonce="-1787433535548338293", oauth_signature="Vj67xMVhSKGjVSmGyOxt7SVv0i8%3D"[\r][\n]"
```

Endpoint - `https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo28/resource/employees/v2/791630875`

Post data to end point: `Filter= Name :EQUALS: David Test`

Content-Type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

It works fine
Thanks

Comment: is this result from the Signet gem?

Comment: No.. I got it using Java V2 sdk. I'm sharing request headers and endpoint details. If it doesn't work in ApiExplorer, then you can try some other RestClients like RestClient plugin of Mozilla. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Manas but unfortunately I need to get this working using the Signet gem in ruby. Its an OAuth compliant library, so it would work with the QBO api out of the box.

Comment: Yes Jason. I understand that. But I've not tried it using Signet. Still I had shared these thinking that the header,content-type info might be useful to you. So that you can compare those with the same generated using the oauth lib which you are using. Thanks

Comment: Hey Manas, The problem is that your headers are just the standard OAuth parameters, and the only way I can verify that my library is generating the same (correct) signature as you is if you were willing to provide me with your OAuth consumer secret and token secret. I provided mine as this is still a test app, one that we will be deleting after we get the api working. As I said previously,the library works properly, correctly signing the request with no body. My question is: does the QBO api require some non-standard oauth modifications to the body parameters?

Comment: You're correct. You need to sign the request body as well. 
Please refer the link below where I had shared a QBO API call without using devkit (using SignPost lib). Hope that will be useful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223603/quickbooks-online-filtering-with-signpost-returns-401-error
Thanks

Comment: Hi Manas, sorry if I'm not being clear. I know that the body parameters need to be signed too. We've used the same library to integrate with 8 other OAuth 1 and 2 api's. We know it generates compliant signatures. My question is regarding any specific non-OAuth related encoding that QBO expects.

Comment: I don't think so. In the signpost ex also, I didn't use anything specific to QBO. It works fine. Unfortunately I've never used ruby before. Otherwise I could have tried the same using ruby and signet.

Comment: Thanks Manas, thats actually pretty helpful. I'll take a look at the signature generation methods for the gem tomorrow. Maybe there's some edge case encoding issues that I can catch with a unit test.

Comment: NP. If you find the solution using ruby and signet, they if possible, please update that in this post. It will be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: I've generated OAuth headers using the tokens which you have shared in your post. You can refer that.

Comment: Hi Manas, Using your settings, I tested the signature generation using the Signet Libray, the [LinkedIn Oauth test console](https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console) and the [Beginners guide to OAuth signing requests](http://hueniverse.com/2008/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iv-signing-requests/) that I posted before. [Here are the settings I used](http://s7.postimg.org/tk3aeyh5n/Linked_In_Screenshot.png), with the base url generated and my signature. Those are 3 different OAuth compliant libraries that are generating the same signature. Could you provide me with your base string?

Comment: I've shared all details in my post. https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo28/resource/employees/v2/791926875
I'm able query(using filter) your QBO account using the tokens which you have shared above. Please take a look at that and let me know how it goes.
Thanks

Comment: unfortunately that does not include your base string (the string that is then signed by HMAC-SHA1) to generate your signature. it will look something like `POST&https%3A%2F%2Fqbo.intuit.com%2Fqbo28%2Fresource%2Femployees%2Fv2%2F791630875&Filter%3DName%2520%253AEQUALS%253A%2520David%2520Test%26oauth_consumer_key%3DqyprdPEfJqU7eOze0Fby9iYhrUS5DQ%26oauth_nonce%3D-1787433535548338293%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1380089100%26oauth_token%3DqyprdJUtDSk7owxVfZlq7JeWO1mtpHBkSMD5GhB02PwIC6N0%26oauth_version%3D1.0`

Comment: That will provide me with all the information I need to figure out exactly why the signature generation is different between your library and the ones that I've tried. It contains the encoded parameter strings

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you btw. You've been alot of help.

Answer (score 0):

See this sample fiddler request with Filter for items in QBO. I cannot paste the fiddler log here. You can  do it for similarly for Employee. The filters should go into the body and encode your header:

**Request-**
POST https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo1/resource/items/v2/723488155

HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="lvprdgF9q4mSQx5A6lKNm3NISXvwIpF16z",oauth_nonce="3740352e-20a4-4d45-af4f-2b783ee20e60",oauth_consumer_key="qyprd7I5WvVnPoiBh1ejZn",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1377106651",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="1OAJXk5uH0sEpYpdhh%2BDMzjQFEs%3D"
Host: qbo.intuit.com
Content-Length: 28
Expect: 100-continue

PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=100

**Response Header-**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 21 Aug 2013 17:37:31 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: qboeuid=10.129.32.5.1377106651774076; path=/; expires=Thu, 21-Aug-14 17:37:31 GMT; domain=.intuit.com
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=82DE11473B5246497B9FDCD8A6DA4C45.c1-pprdqboas30j; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 32525

Comment: hi nimisha, unfortunately I cant do much with this request as I cant verify the signature that you generate without your token secret and consumer secret. Could you possibly get a working request using the parameters and token keys I specify in the question above?

Comment: There's a dotnet example here- https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/6024616   The signatures have been generated for you by Manas. I just wanted to point out the things you need to take care of- The filter should be in body and may sometimes require double encoding as mentioned in the example link.